# How to invoke a exe program within a service program?

Tags: windows-services, createprocess

I'm writing a Windows Services program, it will invoke an external exe file when it is started, such as `notepad.exe`. But it always fails with `"unhandled win32 exception occured"`

My steps:

1. compile the code into an `exe` file: `MemoryStatus.exe`.
2. install service with command: `sc create MemoryStatus binpath=c:\MyServices\MemoryStatus.exe`
3. find the service from windows control panel, and click `Start`.
4. the error happens...

could anyone help to indicate what I did is wrong?

```
void main()
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = _T("MemoryStatus_new_3");
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)**ServiceMain**;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;

    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);

}
void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int error;
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType =   SERVICE_WIN32;
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState =  SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted =  SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP |   SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;
    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(   _T("MemoryStatus_new_3"),   (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler);
    if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0)
    {
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        WriteToLog("Registering Control Handler failed\n");
        return;
    }

    // We report the running status to SCM.
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState =  SERVICE_RUNNING;
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

    // Initialize Service
        startSvc();

    return;
}

void startSvc()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    // Start the child process
    if(CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Program Files\\Source Insight 3\\Insight3.exe"), _T(""), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, FALSE, NULL, &si, &pi))
     {
      CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
      CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
    }
     else 
     {
        hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();//get current process
        TerminateProcess(hProcess,0);         //close process
     }
}
```

Comment: Why does your process commit suicide if CreateProcess() fails? Try removing that behavior and see if the exception goes away.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, but it still failed after removing that. and it's successful when I only just call startSvc() in main() function, but it was failed if it's called through a service...
" Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in wins.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. "

Comment: Does your code really have this line? It shouldn't compile with the extra * * : ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)* *ServiceMain* *;

Comment: Also, you should check for and handle an error from StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Program Files\\Source Insight 3\\Insight3.exe"),
```

Here exists a problem.

store the process name in **an alterable array**.

```
TCHAR szAppName[MAX_PATH];
StringCchCat(szAppName, _countof(szAppName), _T("C:\\Program Files\\Source Insight 3\\Insight3.exe"));
```

Comment: I think it's OK to pass a literal string for the 1st parameter (it is LPCTSTR) but I think you have the right idea. OP is passing _T("") as the 2nd parameter to CreateProcess - MSDN says "this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or **a literal string**). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."  (emphasis added)